# why do i get a syntax error when print tuple?

Tags: python-3.x, tuples

Im getting invalid syntax when I try to print the tuple *zipped*

```
print (zipped)
    ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

```
x = (3,6,7,4,0)
y = (2,6,7,4,1)

zipped = zip(tuple((x,y))

print (zipped)
```

Comment: Missing a parenthesis after your `zip`

Comment: Close parenthesis for zip :  zipped = zip(tuple((x,y)))

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by A.J. Uppal in the comments, you were missing a `)` in the `zipped` statement

```
x = (3,6,7,4,0)
y = (2,6,7,4,1)

zipped = zip(tuple((x,y)))

print (zipped)

# output
<zip object at 0x7f3f1c91c480>
```